# C++ Linux how to use libtar

Tags: c++, linux, linker, tar

I have downloaded and installed libtar.
I have added the header file correctly ( `#include <libtar.h>` ).
I use KDevelop, which automatically recognizes the functions **tar_append_tree** and **tar_open** when I start typing them.
I use cmake with KDevelop (as an option when creating a new project), and so far everything that needed linking (pthreads,shared memory and math) all I had to do was add the appropriate flag in CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS. I know that libtar needs *-ltar* in order to work, but I still get: **undefined reference to tar_open , undefined reference to tar_append_tree**.
Can anyone please help ? I am not aware of any other tar library, and I really need to organize thousands of xml files in a tarball prior to compressing.

edit: I have now found libarchive which is supposed to be much better than libtar. However I am missing something here. How do I explicitly tell KDevelop/Cmake how to link with those libraries ? There is no link flag for libarchive (at least not one I could find on google) and again when I try to compile I get undefined references to the imported functions.

Thank you!

Comment: @vol7ron reptar? Got a link?
@Duck libtar.h is in: /usr/local/include/libtar.h
and /usr/lib/libtar.so.0 and /usr/local/lib/libtar.a

Comment: Do you have /usr/local/lib in your library search path? (-L/usr/local/lib)?

Comment: if you mean LD_LIBRARY_PATH, then no. But /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf has it, so I assume ld should find it, no?

Comment: @Alex: Does running 'ldconfig' changes anything ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there is more than one solution, but here is mine. I created two files

- `FindLIBTAR.cmake` in my project's folder under `cmake/Modules/`
- `libtar.pc` in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig`

#### FindLIBTAR.cmake

```
# - Try to find LIBTAR 
# Find LIBTAR headers, libraries and the answer to all questions.
#
#  LIBTAR_FOUND               True if libuuid got found
#  LIBTAR_INCLUDE_DIRS        Location of libuuid headers 
#  LIBTAR_LIBRARIES           List of libraries to use libuuid 
#

INCLUDE( FindPkgConfig )

IF ( LIBTAR_FIND_REQUIRED )
    SET( _pkgconfig_REQUIRED "REQUIRED" )
ELSE ( LIBTAR_FIND_REQUIRED )
    SET( _pkgconfig_REQUIRED "" )   
ENDIF ( LIBTAR_FIND_REQUIRED )

IF ( LIBTAR_MIN_VERSION )
    PKG_SEARCH_MODULE( LIBTAR ${_pkgconfig_REQUIRED} libtar>=${LIBTAR_MIN_VERSION} )
ELSE ( LIBTAR_MIN_VERSION )
    PKG_SEARCH_MODULE( LIBTAR ${_pkgconfig_REQUIRED} libtar )
ENDIF ( LIBTAR_MIN_VERSION )

IF( NOT LIBTAR_FOUND AND NOT PKG_CONFIG_FOUND )
    FIND_PATH( LIBTAR_INCLUDE_DIRS libtar.h )
    FIND_LIBRARY( LIBTAR_LIBRARIES libtar)

    # Report results
    IF ( LIBTAR_LIBRARIES AND LIBTAR_INCLUDE_DIRS ) 
        SET( LIBTAR_FOUND 1 )
        IF ( NOT LIBTAR_FIND_QUIETLY )
            MESSAGE( STATUS "Found libtar: ${LIBTAR_LIBRARIES}" )
        ENDIF ( NOT LIBTAR_FIND_QUIETLY )
    ELSE ( LIBTAR_LIBRARIES AND LIBTAR_INCLUDE_DIRS )   
        IF ( LIBTAR_FIND_REQUIRED )
            MESSAGE( SEND_ERROR "Could NOT find libtar" )
        ELSE ( LIBTAR_FIND_REQUIRED )
            IF ( NOT LIBTAR_FIND_QUIETLY )
                MESSAGE( STATUS "Could NOT find libtar" )   
            ENDIF ( NOT LIBTAR_FIND_QUIETLY )
        ENDIF ( LIBTAR_FIND_REQUIRED )
    ENDIF ( LIBTAR_LIBRARIES AND LIBTAR_INCLUDE_DIRS )
ENDIF( NOT LIBTAR_FOUND AND NOT PKG_CONFIG_FOUND )

MARK_AS_ADVANCED( LIBTAR_LIBRARIES LIBTAR_INCLUDE_DIRS )
```

#### libtar.pc

```
###########################################################################
# libtar installation details
###########################################################################

prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: libtar
URL: http://www.feep.net/libtar/
Description: Library for Tar files
Version: 1.2.11-8
Libs: -L${libdir} -ltar -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro 
Libs.private: 
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

The `FindLIBTAR.cmake` uses **pkgconfig** to find the `libtar` library and `libtar.pc` is used by  **pkgconfig** to find the library. You can place the cmake file in the same place where CMake places all find files (`/usr/share/cmake/Modules/`) if you don't want to put it in your project's directory. If you do keep it in your project's folder, you will need to add that to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` via:

```
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")
```